# Windows環境のPythonで、接続されているWEBカメラの名前を取得する方法はあるかどうか

Tags: python, windows, opencv

[以下の方法](https://irohaplat.com/python-opencv-camera-id-detection/)で、Windowsで接続されているカメラのIDは取得できるようですが、カメラデバイスの名前は取得できません。
デバイスの名前を取得する方法があれば知りたいです。

```
import cv2

for i1 in range(0, 20): 
    cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture( i1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW )
    if cap1.isOpened(): 
        print("VideoCapture(", i1, ") : Found")
    else:
        print("VideoCapture(", i1, ") : None")
    cap1.release()
```

Pythonの実行環境は、WinPythonとPython 3.10.4です。

**＊追記**
私の環境で[Pygrabber](https://pypi.org/project/pygrabber/)を使用して以下のコードを実行すると、Index番号とカメラ名がズレた形ですが取得できました。正しく取得できる場合もありますが、複数のカメラを接続するとIndex番号がズレるようです。Index番号とカメラ名を同時に正しい状態で取得する方法が知りたいです。

```
from pygrabber.dshow_graph import FilterGraph

devices = FilterGraph().get_input_devices()
for device_index, device_name in enumerate(devices):
    print(str(device_index) + ':  ' + device_name)
```

私と同じ問題が、[windows-capture-device-list 1.1.0のGitHubのissue](https://github.com/yushulx/python-capture-device-list/issues/7)にも上がっているようですが、OpenCVの仕様の問題による不具合のように見えます。カメラの種類というよりも、複数台カメラを接続しているとindex番号がズレるものと思われます。

私の環境は、HPのノートPCの標準カメラと、外部にLogicoolのWebカメラを接続している状況です。GitHubのissueでも、ラップトップでカメラのindex番号がズレると報告されています。

Comment: これは役に立ちますか？https://github.com/pvys/CV-camera-finder

Comment: ありがとうございます。実行環境がWinPythonなせいか分からないですが、指定されたモジュールが見つからないと表示され実行できませんでした。`File "C:\Users\user\Documents\WPy64-31040\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\cvxopt\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>import cvxopt.base
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing base: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。`

Comment: それはおそらくこちらの記事でしょう。[import cvxopt.base --- ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54487277/9014308) 使用している版数のPythonの`Library\bin`フォルダを`PATH`に追加してみてはどうでしょう？ あるいはこちら [Windows - CVXOPT](https://cvxopt.org/install/#windows) の Python 3.5+ の記述に従って準備をするとか？

Comment: このモジュール [windows-capture-device-list 1.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/windows-capture-device-list/) が何かそれらしい機能を持っていそうです。

Comment: windows-capture-device-listも、pygrabberと同様に、カメラの番号とカメラ名が合致しない場合があるようです。少なくとも私の環境ではカメラ名と別のカメラが起動します。

Comment: それは貴方の環境に固有の問題かもしれませんね。そう言えば質問にはソースコードはありますが、使っているカメラ機器は何かとか、表示された結果(正しかった場合とズレた場合)がどうであったか、ズレた状態に何か特徴的な条件等はありそうか、ズレが発生する頻度はどれくらいか、といった情報を整理して追記してみてはどうでしょう？ あるいは誰か対面で依頼できる他の人が居れば、その環境で試してみるとか？

Comment: 私と同じ問題が、windows-capture-device-list 1.1.0のGitHubのissueにも上がっているようですが、OpenCVの仕様の問題による不具合のように見えます。カメラの種類というよりも、複数台カメラを接続しているとindex番号がズレるものと思われます。https://github.com/yushulx/python-capture-device-list/issues/7

Comment: つまり各Issueやその関連リンク先を見る限り、OpenCV自身がデバイスをリスト化するロジックが仕様化されたり、OpenCV自身がインデックス番号に紐づけられた情報を公開するAPIが作られない限り、OpenCV以外の何かが情報を補完しようとしても不整合が生じてしまう、ということのようですね。結局はそのOpenCVの要望Issueに賛成票を付けて実現されるのを待つしかないかもしれませんね。

Comment: そもそも「カメラ名」の取得はどういった理由で必要なのでしょうか？素人考えですがカメラ番号等でも一意にカメラが指定できる方法があるなら、そちらを使えば良さそうにも思います。

Comment: プログラマが自分でOpenCV経由でカメラを開くだけなら、カメラ番号を指定すれば良いですが、ユーザーに配布するようなソフトウェアを作成する場合、カメラ番号では分かりづらく、カメラ名を表示できたほうが良いです。

Answer (score 1):

以下により，カメラ名を一覧できました．

```py
import subprocess
import re

output = (
    subprocess.check_output(["powershell.exe", 'Get-PnpDevice -Class "Image"'])
    .decode("utf-8")
)

camera_infos = output.splitlines()[3:-2]

cameras = [re.split(r"\s{2,}", camera)[2] for camera in camera_infos]
print(cameras)
```

`output`： PowerShellから取得した全カメラ情報の文字列
`camera_infos`：各カメラ情報を要素に持つリスト
`cameras`：`camera_infos`からカメラ名だけに絞ったリスト

Comment: こちらをWinodws11環境で試してみたところ、`subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['powershell.exe', 'Get-PnpDevice -Class "Image"']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`というエラーになりました。

Comment: 私もWindows11で同コードを実行しましたが，カメラ名を取得できました．Powershell側に何かしら問題があるのでしょうか．こちら（https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334592/python-subprocess-returns-non-zero-exit-status-1-minimal-working-sample）を参考にして，PowerShell側でどのようなエラーがでているか確認するのはいかがでしょうか？